# How did this character die?

Tags: god-of-war-2018

Just finished the last boss fight but don't feel this question got answered at all.

> It is about Faye

Speculuation: I'm left with with what I know, I would assume she should be reasonably healthy/fit and athletic (Kratos thought she fought beautifully, she was a former owner of heavy leviathan axe).

Comment: This annoyed me a lot - since her death supposedly is the butterfly effect that caused the series of events described in the end of the story, then why don't we even know how she died? That's just plain bad storytelling.

Answer (score 4):

We don't get any information in game about the cause of death, because Kratos doesn't like talking about it.

But considering his lack of anger at someone/thing, I guess she died of an illness.

It is also a possibility she killed herself, so that Kratos and Atreus would begin their journey.

Comment: +1: if she had been killed, we all know our boy Kratos would be on a rampage